Error while migrating FCM API from legacy to v1: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access
We use FCM on backend to send payment notifications to mobile apps. Eventually, it stopped working because the legacy API was shut down on July 2024. Google provides a migration guide
So here's my new function which sends FCM message:
async function sendFCMInvoicePaidNotificationMessagev2(to, transactionID, mobileNumber, callback) {
    var myAccessToken = await getAccessToken()
    unirest.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/messages:send').headers({
        'Authorization': myAccessToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }).proxy('http://xxxx:1234').send({
        'to': to,
        'priority': 'high',
        'restricted_package_name': config.get('googlePkgName'),
        'notification': {
            'title': 'Invoice # ' + transactionID + ' has been paid. Thank you.'
        },
        'data': {
            'transactionID': transactionID,
            'mobileNumber': mobileNumber
        }
    }).end(function(responseFCM) {
        callback(responseFCM);
    });
}


function getAccessToken() {
    var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const key = require('./service_account.json');
      const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        SCOPES,
        null
      );
      jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        resolve(tokens.access_token);
      });
    });
  }

Running the service, I got this response:

{"statusCode":401,"body":{"error":{"code":401,"message":"Request is
missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access
token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"CREDENTIALS_MISSING","domain":"googleapis.com","metadata":{"method":"google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmService.SendMessage","service":"fcm.googleapis.com"}}]}},"headers":{"www-authenticate":"Bearer
realm="https://accounts.google.com/"","vary":"X-Origin, Referer,
Origin,Accept-Encoding","content-type":"application/json;
charset=UTF-8","date":"Tue, 17 Sep 2024 07:14:13
GMT","server":"scaffolding on
HTTPServer2","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3=":443";
ma=2592000,h3-29=":443";
ma=2592000","accept-ranges":"none","connection":"close","transfer-encoding":"chunked"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"fcm.googleapis.com","port":443,"hostname":"fcm.googleapis.com","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/v1/projects/xxxxxxxx/messages:send","path":"/v1/projects/xxxxxxxx/messages:send","href":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxxxxxx/messages:send"},"method":"post","headers":{"Authorization":{},"Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json","cache-control":"no-cache","content-length":386}}}

Hmmm "Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential"... perhaps I didn't create service_account.json properly? I think I followed Google steps correctly. To generate a private key file for your service account:

In the Firebase console, open Settings > Service Accounts.
Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate
Key.
Securely store the JSON file containing the key.


What's wrong here?

you need to add Authorization type Bearer before your access token
    async function sendFCMInvoicePaidNotificationMessagev2(to, transactionID, mobileNumber, callback) {
    var myAccessToken = await getAccessToken()
    unirest.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/messages:send').headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + myAccessToken,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
    }).proxy('http://xxxx:1234').send({
        'to': to,
        'priority': 'high',
        'restricted_package_name': config.get('googlePkgName'),
        'notification': {
            'title': 'Invoice # ' + transactionID + ' has been paid. Thank you.'
        },
        'data': {
            'transactionID': transactionID,
            'mobileNumber': mobileNumber
        }
    }).end(function(responseFCM) {
        callback(responseFCM);
    });
}

